# Cassandra: Full table scan with token function

Tags: cassandra

I need to read the entire table with `token()` function.

(I cannot use pagination capabilities of a new java client.)

I am not sure what consistency level should be set on my token query.

I am afraid that I will miss rows in the process.

I read that by default `session.execute()` has a consistency level of one. Should I increase it to `QUORUM` or maybe `ALL`?

What's the mechanics behind queries that contain `token()` function?

Comment: What consistency level was the data written with? Whats your replication factor? Have repairs been run? To read all data you can iterate through `SELECT * FROM TABLE` with maybe a different fetch size. Using the tokens is to optimize requests to specific coordinators and breaking it up to scale better, but if just going through it once thats not necessary and will probably take longer to get right then it will to actually do it.

Comment: I am splitting entire address space into token ranges. I have a table with billions of records. Each token range can be claimed by one worker at a time. It allows me to scale my data migration tool better. I am not sure if there is a chance that I might lose tokens and along with them data if I run a query like below with consistency level one: select token(a), a from myTable where token(a) >= ? and token(a) <= ? limit 100 I do not care much if my data in the batch will be 100% up-to-date as I have a process that is recording delta changes in the other data store. Thoughts? @ChrisLohfink

Comment: @ChrisLohfink Will not be the `SELECT * FROM TABLE` with fetch size a full table scan still?